# What style notched trowel should I use to lay 6"x24" ceramic on a shower wall?

Tags: tiling, thinset

I inherited a 3/8" square notched trowel and a 3/16" v-notched trowel.

- Which is the correct for laying down a coat of thin-set prior to attaching 6" x 24" tile to a wall?
- When is the correct time to use either trowel?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking 3 different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either.  If your walls are perfectly flat and the tile is too then 1/4 will be fine.

What would I normally do with 6x24?  I would use a 1/4" trowel but backbutter all of the pieces.  The tiles need to be pushed firmly in place too.  My main concern with this type of tile is the bowing in the middle.

Comment: +1 for the comment about bowing; I hadn't considered it.  It seems like back-buttering would always be the easiest way tot tile.  Is there a reason the people don't always back-butter tile?

Comment: Because it is one extra step and also brings in an added element to the height of the tile.  If you use almost no thinset and squeeze it good (what bad tilers do) the finish job is easy and it is really flat - obviously this tile will have major problems over time but their check has cashed.  The more thinset involved more chance to mess up height... just take your time.

Comment: NO not a 1/4 inch trowel...NEVER! Use a 1/2 x 1/2. A 3/8 trowel is good for an 12x12 or smaller tile, your v- notch is good for smaller backsplash tiles.

Comment: @Stevo - Please read my answer.  I am suggesting back buttering.  You would not use a 1/2" trowel after back buttering - way too much thinset.  You are correct if there is no back buttering.

Answer (score 1):

Most tile manufacturers will have a specific trowel recommendation for their tile. It may not be either of the ones you own. In that case you'll buy another one. In any case, it is normally clearly stated in the installation instructions for the tile. The size and shape of the notches affects both the total amount of thinset (so a 3/8 X 3/8 X 3/8 notched trowel lays down an amount of thinset that would be 3/16" thick if flattened completely) and the way that the ridged thinset interacts with the tile as it is placed (V's have a bit more give than square-notches as the tile is embedded.)

Read and follow the tile manufacturer's installation instructions.

Comment: @Tester101 - why don't we just post RTFM for every question?  Almost every question on the site can be answered that way.  Really poor logic for this site.

Comment: @DMoore Why is it poor logic?  The manufacturer takes the time to write the documentation, to tell you how to use their product. Why wouldn't you take advantage of that knowledge?

Comment: Well @Tester101 in this specific case we are talking about tile.  I have bought tile maybe 150-300 times in my life.  Never received a manual with any.  Going to the manufacturer's website can sometimes be a web of crap too.  And to add to that we are really talking about two products that may have overlapping jurisdiction - thinset and tile - and may have different advice.  An answer should refer to the manual or the manual should be very easy to find for that instance.

Comment: @DMoore I haven't bought tile that often, but any time I have, trowel and mortar recommendations were on the box (if I recall correctly).

Comment: @Tester101 - I often keep tile boxes because they can hold a lot of weight - have 5 different boxes downstairs... couple for the TileShop and the rest who knows.  Sometimes just a manufacturing code on box, sometimes a manufacturer name stamped on them... no instructions.  Would like to see this special tile you get though.

Comment: @DMoore I could be mistaken, as I've said I don't buy tile that often.  Even so, finding instructions online, or through phone support is typically not that difficult.

Comment: -1 (and flagging) for RTFM per [stack exchange guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments/23629#23629)

Comment: @Tester101 the box only specifies preferred and minium grout joint size.  The manufacturer "stone logic" doesn't seem to exist on the internet.

Comment: @virtualxtc Reading the manual is an important part of DIY, as different manufacturers recommend different things.  While users on StackOverflow may not enjoy reading manuals, we here at DIY.StackExchange very much enjoy cuddling up by a warm fire with a good technical document.

Comment: @virtualxtc I think the manufacturer of the tile is [StonePeak Ceramics](http://www.stonepeakceramics.com/), though I could be wrong.  Is there a phone number on the packaging?

Comment: @Tester101 strange, I can't find my tile on there, but my guess is you are correct.  However my question remains: FTFM: "Use the appropriate trowel notch size to ensure proper bedding of the tile, brick or stone selected. Work the latex Portland cement mortar
into good contact with the substrate and comb with notched side of trowel."

Comment: @Tester101 also no phone number for the vendor.